# One column fixed, no scrolling, while the other scrolls as usual?

Tags: html, css, scroll, sticky

I'm using Cargo Collective for a portfolio site, and I have two divs side by side on one of my project pages. I want to make one of the divs (the left one) fixed with no scroll and the other one normal with scroll.

Any ideas how I can accomplish my goal here? Here is a link to one of the pages, for better understanding of the issue: https://laurenacampora.fun/As-Featured-In

Here are some things I've noticed as I try to do this myself:

Using "position: fixed" in my CSS causes the two columns to overlap
Using "overflow: hidden" doesn't seem to do anything
Whatever I do needs to be disabled on mobile where I'd like to have both columns collapse into one still (as they currently do).
Cargo Collective does not seem to allow me to import SASS or SCSS files so I can't use a solution using one of those things.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your post needs to show code. Ideally it'll be in a demo, which you can build with the editor. Also take the [tour].